# import scipy error: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'

Tags: python, scipy

I use `Anaconda3@windows` to import `scipy(v1.0.0)` but I have an error when compiling. I have checked other similar cases online but found no solution, does anyone have any idea?

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
```

**The error msg**

```
ImportError
Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-12-eb63b9337447> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import scipy

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in
<module>()
    116     del _NumpyVersion
    117 
--> 118     from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
    119 
    120     from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_ccallback.py
in <module>()
----> 1 from . import _ccallback_c
      2 
      3 import ctypes
      4 
      5 PyCFuncPtr = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p).__bases__[0]

ImportError: cannot import name '_ccallback_c'
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and tried all recommended solutions (re-install in many different ways), but nothing worked. 
What helped a lot is to read documentation more carefully (https://www.scipy.org/install.html) 
In my case, scipy library also required some latest versions of other libraries to be installed, so I run:
python -m pip install numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose

Now everything works fine.

Comment: In my case, it seems like I didn't have all necessary and somehow linked to scipy packages, like ipython, jupyter, sympy and nose. So I found this solution in documentation for scipy installation, basically list of required libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Solution found!

1. remove scipy (entire folder), in my computer where in C:\Users(your name)\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\scipy*
2. download scipy from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
3. re-install by pip install scipy-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (my os is windows-64bit)

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Daria Simonova, try
`conda update numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose`
in case you are using Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

After digging in, to give the full background on this, first of all SciPy relies on having NumPy already installed.  The SciPy wheel's `setup.py` file uses NumPy functionality to configure and install the wheel.

SciPy `setup.py`:

```
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from numpy.distutils.core import setup
    setup(**configuration(top_path='').todict())
```

Secondly, when just trying to use the wheel, if you run into this error, you can see after inspecting the wheel's files that the reason is the binary wheels have a naming convention where the shared object file, here it's called `_ccallback_c.so`, is instead named based on the architecture that the binary  wheel supports.  When trying to import the shared object by file name in `/_lib/_ccallback.py` it can't find it, hence this error (line 1 in `/_lib/_ccallback.py`) because, instead of being named `_ccallback_c.so` it's called `_ccallback_c.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` or another architecture variation:

```
from . import _ccallback_c
```

These file names may be an artifact of having not run the NumPy setup process yet or something related to Cython, that I'm not quite sure about.  But the easiest fix is to change the .whl extension to .zip and rename all those relevant .so files to not contain the architecture snippet.  Then change .zip -> .whl and it should be good to go.